# Android App integration with other websites

Tags: android, web-services, http, rest

I am currently a student of Android.
My aim is to develop Android Apps that talk with different websites and exchange/process/return data.
But I am really not sure what should be starting point.

Coming from a backend development I can put the layout for backend development as follows

a) Understand Relational DB concepts

b) SQL

c) PLSQL

d) Procedures/Functions

e) Solve realworld problems
....etc

Similarly can someone tell me what should be starting point for learning Android integration.

HTTP or Web Services or REST API or JSON/XML or anything else

All these terms are new to me and when I googled/wikied the terms I can (kinda) grasp what they mean but I am not able to see the big picture as to how they fit etc...wrt integrating an app with a website.

TLDR.what should be the starting point for learning Android Integration ?.

PS : If this is a wrong forum, then do let me know which forum to post this on. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so general, and there is no clear answer for it, and you are not ready to build a real app unless you can answer it by your own, so you need to know more about each term of the above, then your question will be "what is the best practice?"

You can start from below:

[IBM: Using XML and JSON with Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-andbene1/)

[XML vs JSON Based Web Services: Which is the Best Choice?](http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/04/01/xml-vs-json-web-services-best-choice)

[XML vs JSON parsing in Android](http://www.majidkhosravi.com/xml-vs-json-android/)

[JSON or XML in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/JSON_or_XML_in_Android)

By the way many developers prefere JSON, because JSON is simpler than XML/SOAP and has less overhead, and payload will be smaller than the XML representation, beside Android has JSON parseing APIs.